# VBA Access: Create a new button in a 2010 Access form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to create a new button on a form Access 2010. If I click on a button to create a new button on the form, but I can not create the button if the form view is different from the design view (Error 6062: You must be in Design or Layout View to create or delete controls). How I can create the button with VBA code? Thanks.

```
  Private Sub Command2_Click()
     Dim boton As CommandButton

     Set boton = CreateControl(Me.Name, acCommandButton, acFooter)
        With newButton
            .Visible = True
            .Enabled = True
            .Caption = "prueba"
        End With
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much easier way to accomplish what you want. You can create the button on the form add make Visible = False on the property sheet. Then your code would just be:

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
Me.Command3.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Then when you click the button it would make the button appear on the form. What are you trying to accomplish by creating the command button? Is there a reason this method is insufficient?